# Initializing Firebase Throws an Error - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-android

While I was trying to set up Firebase, I learned that I need to initialize Firebase after the *last updates*. But when I run:

`Firebase.initializeApp();`

I get an **error** saying:

[_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVhwY.png)

I tried to *remove* it, afterwords everything **worked fine**.
This is the code I am running:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(SignIn());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documents this is how you can initialize firebase in your app:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); //Make sure you imported firebase_core
  runApp(SignIn());
 );
}
```

Happy Fluttering :)